# Removing my answer because it pointed the questioner to a video tutorial

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, specific-answer, link-only-answers

I recently answered a user question by directing the questioner to a video tutorial that specifically dealt with his question. The person asking the question found the tutorial addressed all his issues plus a few other things that he would have done incorrectly. I could have supplied the code for a solution however it would have been lengthy and complex to explain.

The idea here is the old adage you can give a hungry person (the questioner) as fish (the code) or teach him how to fish (the tutorial), So at any rate somebody in authority hid the post. I think this is not what we should be about. In fact the tutorial provides a much more thoroughly explained answer than I could have provided as it is at least 20 minutes long. So what did deleting the answer accomplish?

Nothing in my opinion but to keep people that may have a similar question from getting the benefit of a correct and complete understanding of how to solve their problem.

Comment: This sounds like a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Note that just a few days ago, there was a [meta] question about mass-editing answers because a site that has been linked in a lot of answers went dead. Incidents like this are *precisely* the reason why the rule that "any post must be completely standalone without requiring any external resources whatsoever" exists.

Comment: "I could have supplied the code for a solution however it would have been lengthy and complex to explain." – That's not a problem. The character limit is 30000, and it is perfectly normal for a good answer to require a couple of days of work, just like a good question requires a couple of days of work.

Comment: If a question cannot be answered in a few pages of code and text, it is probably too broad.

Answer (score 22):

A link to a long, off-site tutorial is not an answer to a question, any more than a link to the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/) would be an answer to a question. Sure, someone could pretty much find out the answer to any problem they were having by reading and understanding that document, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. We are, for better or worse, a site that provides fish. We do hope that the fish will be provided along with an explanation of how they can be caught, since that makes the answer more generally useful. But if the fish aren't included, then it's really not an answer. (That's not to say that all answers require code, or that you can't post conceptual answers. It's just a way of saying that the direct answer to the question needs to actually appear *in the answer*. Indirect "you could have figured this out yourself" answers aren't really appropriate.)

There is also a more practical problem: links to off-site resources regularly become inaccessible. Dead links are a chronic problem, especially since our Q&A is expected to stand the test of time. We have plenty of Q&A from 2008 or 2009 that users still find useful, yet many of the links that were up at the time have become dead now, thus diminishing the usefulness of this "old" content. That's unfortunate. To help avoid that problem now, we have developed [standards for what a good answer must include](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). A link is not sufficient. While you are encouraged to include supplemental links in your posts, they must be merely supplemental—all required information must be quoted and/or summarized from the link, in case that link becomes inaccessible. Another way of stating this is, answers must be *standalone*, meaning that they remain useful even if all hyperlinks are stripped out of them.

The moderator even told you this in a comment underneath the deleted answer:

> Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Your answer was a pretty classic case of this. You even admitted as such, saying:

> Rather than go through the how to details here I suggest you go to a tutorial on YouTube located <here>.

That just doesn't work on Stack Overflow.

Moderators regularly delete answers that do not meet our standards, generally in response to flags raised on those answers by the community. This is one of the key quality control mechanisms used on Stack Overflow. While you cannot immediately undelete an answer that has been deleted by a moderator, it is possible to *edit* that answer, bringing it into compliance with our requirements. At that point, once the answer is brought into shape, it can be undeleted by a moderator, making it visible again.

If our rules about posts being self-contained mean that you need to write longer answers with more explanation, then so be it. We don't have a problem with that. The character limit for posts is around 30,000, so you're unlikely to exceed that limit even with a thorough explanation. If you do, then the question is surely too broad for Stack Overflow's Q&A and should be closed on that basis (until such time as it can be edited to sharpen the focus).